# Reorder legend survfit

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have made a regression that looks like this:

```
survfit(Surv(YearsToEvent, Event) ~ CancerType, data = RegressionData)
```

From that I get an output table like this (I removed some of the columns for readability):

```
          n 
Cancer A  100  
Cancer B  200
```

However, when I plot the output using `ggsurvplot` where I have a plot + a table with "number at risk", I want to be able to manually adjust the order of the legend. That is, I want to be able to put `Cancer B` before `Cancer A`. I found a similar thread here on SO: [How to reorder strata in survfit object for ggsurvplot legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120869/how-to-reorder-strata-in-survfit-object-for-ggsurvplot-legend). However, I did not find any answer in it. I have tried to sort the data frame `RegressionData` before the regression, without sucess.

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you could achieve what you want:

The main step is to transfrom the grouping variable to factor class. Then you can define the levels by hand:

The other steps are the same:

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)

lung1 <- lung %>% 
  mutate(sex = factor(sex, levels = c(2, 1)))
  
ggsurvplot(
  fit = survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung1),
  risk.table = TRUE,
  xlab = "Days", 
  ylab = "Overall survival probability")
```

[image]